# Nhibernate CreateSQLQuery Stored Procedure result to non mapped class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, stored-procedures, hql

In my application I want to get data from a stored procedured where the table is not mapped in the application. In this stored procedure I added aliases to the column names which respond to the properties in my class.

**HQL:**

```
return Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec PER_PrikklokSaldi :IDPers :jaar :maand")
            .AddScalar("Description", NHibernateUtil.String)
            .AddScalar("StartSaldo", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
            .AddScalar("Plus", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
            .AddScalar("Minus", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
            .AddScalar("EndSaldo", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
            .SetParameter("IDPers", _employeeId)
            .SetParameter("jaar", _year)
            .SetParameter("maand", _month)
            .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(ClockInfoSaldi)))
            .List<ClockInfoSaldi>()
            .ToList();
```

**Class:**

```
public class ClockInfoSaldi
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int StartSaldo { get; set; }
    public int Plus { get; set; }
    public int Minus { get; set; }
    public int EndSaldo { get; set; }
}
```

**Stored Procedure result in MS SQL Management Studio:**

[image: sp result]

I can run this:

```
var test = Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec PER_PrikklokSaldi :IDPers :jaar :maand")
            .SetParameter("IDPers", _employeeId)
            .SetParameter("jaar", _year)
            .SetParameter("maand", _month)
```

But when I run the first mentioned HQL code I get this error: {"could not execute query\r\n[ exec PER_PrikklokSaldi @p0 @p1 @p2 ]\r\n  Name:IDPers - Value:827  Name:jaar - Value:2014  Name:maand - Value:1\r\n[SQL: exec PER_PrikklokSaldi @p0 @p1 @p2]"}

InnerException: {"Incorrect syntax near '@p1'."}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is hidden in the exception *(and mostly in this part: "Incorrect syntax near '@p1'.")*:

> {"could not execute query\r\n[ exec PER_PrikklokSaldi @p0 **@p1** @p2 ]\r\n Name:IDPers - Value:827 Name:jaar - Value:2014 Name:maand - Value:1\r\n[SQL: exec PER_PrikklokSaldi @p0 @p1 @p2]"}

The parameters should be split by comma:

```
var test = Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec PER_PrikklokSaldi :IDPers, :jaar, :maand")
        .SetParameter("IDPers", _employeeId)
        .SetParameter("jaar", _year)
        .SetParameter("maand", _month)
```

or maybe rather this *(for sql server)*

```
"exec PER_PrikklokSaldi @IDPers=:IDPers, @jaar=:jaar, @maand=:maand"
```

To execute this instead

> exec PER_PrikklokSaldi @p0, @p1, @p2

Comment: I did not know that but it still does not work if I try to get the result in my object. I now get this error:     {"could not execute query\r\n[ exec PER_PrikklokSaldi ?, ?, ? ]\r\n  Name:IDPers - Value:827  Name:jaar - Value:2014  Name:maand - Value:1\r\n[SQL: exec PER_PrikklokSaldi ?, ?, ?]"}

Comment: Good to see some progress ;) but there is another row(s) of this exception... and there I do expect the asnwer (e.g. SP not exists). So please: **provide the complete stack** *(of the new exception)*. I mean something like incorrect syntax near

Comment: Thank you for helping me! The innerexception is {"Invalid read attempt; there is no data available."} => rough translation from a dutch error.

Comment: I guess, that must be exception inside of SP or related to the returned value.. but the rest should work

Comment: I can execute the SP perfectly in management studio. I guess it's something related to returning the value in a specific class that is not mapped in NHibernate. Is it even possible?

Comment: I did not know, that you are missing Transformer. This is one solution. You can also return `List<object[]>()` without any explicit mapping. Good luck with NHibernate

Answer (score 0):

This solution works now! I get a list of ClockInfoData objects with the correct values from the stored procedure.

```
return Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec PER_PrikklokData :IDPers, :jaar, :maand")
            .SetParameter("IDPers", _employeeId)
            .SetParameter("jaar", _year)
            .SetParameter("maand", _month)
            .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(ClockInfoData)))
            .List<ClockInfoData>()
            .ToList();
```