# Calling stored procedure using NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, stored-procedures, nhibernate-mapping

I can't get this stored procedure call to work. I keep getting a "Additional information: Parameter UserName does not exist as a named parameter in [LockUser]" message

```
using (var session = sm.OpenSession())         
{
    var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("LockUser")
    .SetString("UserName", User.UserName.ToString());                  
}
```

mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>                                                        <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
namespace="Models.Mappings" assembly="Intranet">
<sql-query name="LockUser">
    <property name="UserName"/>
    exec LockUser :UserName
</sql-query>
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Their is a typo in your mapping, I assume this is not the full mapping... Also does your SP return anything?

Comment: Is this for SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: @hikizume Then the parameter should be `@UserName` instead of `:UserName` right?

Comment: @DavidG don't think so as far as I know. If I change it I get the same error anyway

Comment: @Rippo You're correct, it's not the full mapping. Don't know what you mean by SP though

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two features.

[17.2. Named SQL queries](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-namedqueries)

small cited snippet:

```
<sql-query name="persons">
    <return alias="person" class="eg.Person"/>
    SELECT person.NAME AS {person.Name},
           person.AGE AS {person.Age},
           person.SEX AS {person.Sex}
    FROM PERSON person
    WHERE person.NAME LIKE :namePattern
</sql-query>
```

usage:

```
IList people = sess.GetNamedQuery("persons")
    .SetString("namePattern", namePattern)
    .SetMaxResults(50)
    .List();
```

So as we can see there must be call **`GetNamedQuery()`**

Or you can use

[Chapter 17. Native SQL](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql)

small cited snippet:

```
sess.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE, DOG_ID FROM CATS")
    .AddEntity(typeof(Cat));
```

Summary: for named queries, we have to use `.GetNamedQuery()`. We can also use `.CreateSQLQuery()` to build SQL ourselves. Check also this for working example: [Nhibernate CreateSQLQuery Stored Procedure result to non mapped class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755828/)

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I'm no closer to achieving it though. I need to use a named query like you mentioned, but for an update. I've been able to find many examples for selects but not for updates.

Comment: 1) get your named query via `GetNamedQuery()` 2) fill in params via `.SetString()` or `.SetParameter()` 3) call the **`ExecuteUpdate()`** That must work. The essential here is ExecuteUpdate ... which does the trick in comparison with what you have seen - SELECT

Comment: No cigar. If I change it to GetNamedQuery the error changes to named query not known

Comment: Look, try this `Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec LockUser :UserName").SetString("UserName", User.UserName).ExecuteUpdate();` Be sure, that you can use NHibernate to execute the SP *(stored procedure)*. If this won't work for you, take a cigi and try later... issue will be elswhere

Comment: Is xml mapping a embedded resource? Like @RadimKöhler mentions ExecuteUpdate() is your friend